# Using FOR loop for finding out the sum of variables?

Tags: r, loops, dataframe

I have a data frame that has 6,497,651 observations of 6 variables that I got from the National Emissions Inventory website and it has the following variables:

```
fips    SCC       Pollutant     Emissions    type    year
09001   10100401  PM25          15.14        POINT   1999
09001   10100402  PM25          234.75       POINT   1999
```

Where `fips` is the county code, `SCC` is name of the source string, `Pollutant` is the type of pollutant (PM2.5 emission in this case), `Emissions` indicates the amount of the pollutant emitted in tons, `type` is the type of source where pollutant was emitted (road, non-road, point, etc) and `year` notes down years from 1999 to 2008.

Basically, I have to plot a simple line plot to showcase the change in the level of emissions according to each year. Now, the year 1999 alone has over a thousand observations; same goes for the rest of the years till 2008. The problem is not at all difficult since I can easily form a new data frame for each year with the sum of all the emissions recorded and then row bind all those subsetted data frames. But a more efficient and tidier way to accomplish this might be to use the FOR loop where I can calculate the sum of all the values under 'Emissions' according to each year and store all that information into a new data frame, but I am stuck on where to start. How do I enter the exact syntax that will calculate the sum of values according to each year? I should be having a data frame that looks something like this:

```
Year    Emissions
```

Where `Emissions` notes down the sum of values of all emissions in that specific year.

Comment: Don't loop it, ddply it. See [ddply](http://www.inside-r.org/packages/cran/plyr/docs/ddply). For instance: `ddply(data, .(Year), function(x){em_sum <- sum(x$Emissions) data.frame(Emissions = em_sum)})` Something to that effect. If you must loop, something to note is that beyond 1000 iterations (arguably fewer) there are generally more efficient ways to obtain a desired outcome.

Comment: maybe `with(mydata, tapply(Emissions, year, sum))`. It's best to add some actual sample data with your expected outcome.

Comment: Added details as requested by @Pierre

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`data.table` package is probably the most efficient package to handle things like that. The syntax to calculate sum of emissions for every year would be like that (assuming your data is stored in `dt`):

```
library(data.table)
dt=data.table(dt)
dt[,.(Emissions=sum(Emissions)),by=year]
```

Comment: I'd suggest using `setDT()` instead of `data.table()` which returns a data.table from data.frame without deep copying. It has been there since a long time.

Answer (score 0):

A `dplyr/ggplot` option.  We group by 'year', get the `sum` of 'Emissions' using `summarise` and plot with `ggplot`.

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2) 
df1 %>%
   group_by(year) %>% 
   summarise(Emissions=sum(Emissions)) %>%
   ggplot(., aes(x=year, y=Emissions))+
   geom_line()
```

Or this can be done directly within `ggplot`

```
ggplot(df1, aes(x=year, y=Emissions)) + 
                stat_summary(fun.y='sum', geom='line')
```